How to get the available Python versions on Remote Node?
I have some machines with different properties and different installed versions of Python. Now I want to write a task that returns all available Python versions on every machine (some have 2.7.x, some 3.8.x and others are in between).
Depending on that I want to register the highest version for later tasks.
I tried to filter the output of ansible_facts.packages but I fail at using filters in YAML.
- name: Gather the package facts 
  ansible.builtin.package_facts: 
    manager: auto 
    strategy: all 
- name: Check whether a package called python is installed 
  ansible.builtin.debug: 
    msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['python*'] }} versions of foobar are installed!" 

I need it to return the machine and every Python version on that specific machine.

Can't you just use ansible_python_version?

To clarify, you have different versions on individual machines?

On a RHEL 9.4 System with Python 3.9.18 a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  pre_tasks:

  - package_facts:

  tasks:

  - debug:
      var: ansible_python_version

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages[item] }}"
    loop: "{{ ansible_facts.packages | select('search', regex) }}"
    vars:
      regex: 'python*'


will result for ansible_python_version simply into an output of
TASK [debug] *******************
ok: [localhost] =>
  ansible_python_version: 3.9.18

from Ansible Interpreter Discovery.
For ansible_facts.packages it will result into an output of
TASK [debug] ************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-setuptools-wheel) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-setuptools-wheel
    release: 12.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 53.0.0
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-setuptools) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-setuptools
    release: 12.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 53.0.0
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-dbus) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-dbus
    release: 2.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 1.2.18
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-six) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-six
    release: 9.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 1.15.0
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-gobject-base-noarch) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-gobject-base-noarch
    release: 6.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 3.40.1
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-gobject-base) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-gobject-base
    release: 6.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 3.40.1
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-iniparse) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-iniparse
    release: 45.el9
    source: rpm
    version: '0.4'
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-inotify) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-inotify
    release: 25.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 0.9.6
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-distro) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-distro
    release: 7.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 1.5.0
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-libcomps) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-libcomps
    release: 1.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 0.1.18
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-chardet) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-chardet
    release: 5.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 4.0.0
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-decorator) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-decorator
    release: 6.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 4.4.2
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-ethtool) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-ethtool
    release: 2.el9
    source: rpm
    version: '0.15'
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-pysocks) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-pysocks
    release: 12.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 1.7.1
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-pyyaml) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-pyyaml
    release: 6.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 5.4.1
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-systemd) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-systemd
    release: 18.el9
    source: rpm
    version: '234'
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-gpg) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-gpg
    release: 6.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 1.15.1
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-ptyprocess) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-ptyprocess
    release: 12.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 0.6.0
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-pexpect) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-pexpect
    release: 7.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 4.8.0
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-dateutil) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: 1
    name: python3-dateutil
    release: 7.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 2.8.1
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-pyparsing) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-pyparsing
    release: 1.el9ap
    source: rpm
    version: 3.0.9
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-packaging) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-packaging
    release: 2.el9ap
    source: rpm
    version: '21.3'
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-pycparser) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-pycparser
    release: 2.el9pc
    source: rpm
    version: '2.21'
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-cffi) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-cffi
    release: 3.el9ap
    source: rpm
    version: 1.15.0
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-cryptography) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-cryptography
    release: 1.el9ap
    source: rpm
    version: 38.0.4
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-resolvelib) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-resolvelib
    release: 5.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 0.5.4
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-xmltodict) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-xmltodict
    release: 15.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 0.12.0
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-pip-wheel) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-pip-wheel
    release: 8.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 21.2.3
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-sssdconfig) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-sssdconfig
    release: 6.el9_4
    source: rpm
    version: 2.9.4
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-file-magic) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-file-magic
    release: 16.el9
    source: rpm
    version: '5.39'
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-libselinux) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-libselinux
    release: 1.el9
    source: rpm
    version: '3.6'
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-libsemanage) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-libsemanage
    release: 1.el9
    source: rpm
    version: '3.6'
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-setools) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-setools
    release: 1.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 4.4.4
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-urllib3) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-urllib3
    release: 5.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 1.26.5
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-requests) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-requests
    release: 8.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 2.25.1
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-cloud-what) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-cloud-what
    release: 1.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 1.29.40
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-audit) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-audit
    release: 2.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 3.1.2
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-sss) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-sss
    release: 6.el9_4
    source: rpm
    version: 2.9.4
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-librepo) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-librepo
    release: 2.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 1.14.5
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-libdnf) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-libdnf
    release: 8.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 0.69.0
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-hawkey) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-hawkey
    release: 8.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 0.69.0
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-policycoreutils) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-policycoreutils
    release: 2.1.el9
    source: rpm
    version: '3.6'
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-rpm) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-rpm
    release: 29.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 4.16.1.3
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-subscription-manager-rhsm) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-subscription-manager-rhsm
    release: 1.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 1.29.40
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-dnf) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-dnf
    release: 9.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 4.14.0
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-dnf-plugins-core) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-dnf-plugins-core
    release: 13.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 4.3.0
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-pip) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-pip
    release: 8.el9
    source: rpm
    version: 21.2.3
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-idna) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python3-idna
    release: 7.el9_4.1
    source: rpm
    version: '2.10'
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-libs) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3-libs
    release: 3.el9_4.1
    source: rpm
    version: 3.9.18
ok: [localhost] => (item=python-unversioned-command) =>
  msg:
  - arch: noarch
    epoch: null
    name: python-unversioned-command
    release: 3.el9_4.1
    source: rpm
    version: 3.9.18
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: python3
    release: 3.el9_4.1
    source: rpm
    version: 3.9.18

if all keys are selected which begins with python. One may also have a look into the output of
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages.keys() }}"

The issue with the initial question was ansible_facts.packages['python*'], as globbing in the variable name and the dict will not work. One need to select the dict keys differently and as shown above.
Similar Q&A

Checking Python version through Ansible

and others which might be helpful in this case

Ansible: Install Python module only if it not exist
Ansible: How to install a package only if same version not installed?


This only returns one interpreter version, right? Question seemed to want all versions available

@OneCricketeer, actually no. The tasks with ansible_facts.packages | select('search', regex) will return all Python versions available, but not give an answer to the question which was not asked "Which of the packages starting with python are interpreters?".

That task returns all OS managed python packages, of one interpreter? What if I had both python 3.8 and 3.9 installed? Say one was created by Conda?

@OneCricketeer, "That task returns all OS managed python packages, of one interpreter?", yes, depending on how they were installed. But the question does not provide the kind of OS, the kind of Python installation(s), how there were installed and in which way, possible paths and so on ... The only hint given was ansible_facts.packages.
